# What causes the array in the following code not to be printed?

Tags: c, puzzle

There is something wrong with the code below... Could someone explain to me whats the problem and why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

 #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

 int main()
 {
  int d;

  for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
      printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` unsigned (e.g unsigned long long), `d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)` is compared as unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **sizeof** operator:
...

"The value of the result is implementation-deﬁned, and its type (an unsigned integer type)
is size_t, deﬁned in < stddef.h > (and other headers)." - C99 standard.

**Conversions**:
...

"Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other  operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is  converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer type." - C99 standard.

The int d(-1) is converted to (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2) type which is sizeof return type(an unsigned integer). This is usually done by reinterpreting the bits as an unsigned value => -1 signed integer = 0xFFFFFFFF(if int has 32 bits) unsigned integer.

You are trying to compare 0xFFFFFFFF with 0x5(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)  which is false.

You should have a warning... signed/unsigned mismatch...

[C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/projects#9899)

Answer (score 3):

Usual arithmetic conversions.

In the `<=` expression the `int` value `-1` is converted to the unsigned type of `sizeof` and becomes a huge value and the `<=` expression is then false.

Use:

```
for(d=-1;d <= (int) (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below changes

#include

```
 #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

 int main()
 {
  int d,k;
k=TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2;
  for(d=-1;d <=k ;d++)
      printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

  return 0;
}
```